# Mysql Trigger to delete all rows older then timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, triggers

I am having some syntax error in my Trigger.

I am trying to check after each insert if the table is bigger than 5000 rows and if so, delete all rows older than 10 min in 1000 chunks stopping when the table reaches under 1000 rows.

here is the code

```
CREATE trigger my_trigger after insert ON myTable 
    IF (SELECT count(Uuid) from myTable) > 5000
    THEN
        WHILE (SELECT count(Uuid) from myTable) > 1000
            DELETE from myTable
                where myTable.created < (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
        END WHILE
    END IF;
```

how can I delete all rows older then timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax error comes from your invalid `WHILE` clause. A correct form could be:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(Uuid) INTO @cnt FROM myTable;
WHILE (@cnt > 1000)
...
```

However, this could lead to an (almost) infinite loop, if there are more than 1000 records younger than 10 minutes (sure, eventually all records will be older than 10 minutes :).

But the major issue here is that ([reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-program-restrictions.html)):

> A (...) trigger cannot modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the (...) trigger.

However you can achieve a *similar* effect with an [`EVENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events.html) (that would purge your table every now and then).

Comment: TY, an event is a better solution indeed and that @cnt did the trick with the Syntax.

Comment: @RandomSeed - The link for "Event" is broken